# Peach fails when I use the attribute xmlns

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, fuzzing, peach

I want to create [Peach](http://community.peachfuzzer.com/WhatIsPeach.html) `DataModel` which would fuzzy XML (To be precise, the [Content_Types].xml from .docx). But when I create a `XmlElement` attribute xmlns, then peach crashes with Unhandled Exception: `System.ArgumentException`

It works:

```
<DataModel name="TestTemplate">
        <XmlElement elementName="Types">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="xmlnsSOMELETTERS">
                        <String value="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
.......
</DataModel>
```

It not works:

```
<XmlElement elementName="Types">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="xmlns">
                        <String value="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
```

Can you help me with this?

[Full xml](http://pastebin.com/H75w1gR8)

Comment: `xmlns` are not attributes. The are namespace declarations. You can't create them with `XmlAttribute`. (BTW, read through the tag description of [fuzzing], I am pretty sure that's not what your meant.)

Comment: I have to think of something to fazzer "Peach" generated element that looks like <Types xmlns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
...
</ Types>

Comment: @Tomalak: A tag for [Peach](http://community.peachfuzzer.com/WhatIsPeach.html) would probably be better, but 'fuzzing' isn't that far off.

Comment: @kjhughes Tag stub created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tomalak mentioned in comments, `xmlns` isn't an attribute but a namespace declaration, so you have to handle it differently.

In [Peach](http://community.peachfuzzer.com/WhatIsPeach.html), there is a special attribute (`ns`) on [XmlElement](http://community.peachfuzzer.com/WhatIsPeach.html) to use for namespace declarations.

Comment: <XmlElement elementName="Types" ns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">